# installing sets/groups/collections of ports using macports

Tags: macports

So I just installed macports (most recent version, on OS X 10.8.2). I now want to install ports. It seems that I need to search and install individual ports (though dependencies will be automatically installed for me), which are compiled instead of installed as a binary. Is this really the only way? Can I not ask to install a whole set/group of ports? (say everything related to latex)? Or perhaps there are some collections of useful ports which I can choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macports contains a number of metaports, such as texlive, which are virtual packages which make it easier to install a group of ports.
E.g. installing the texlive package will set up everything you need for basic latex work. Some more advanced packages will still need to be installed by hand.

I do not know about a list of "ports that everybody should install".